# Ubuntu 20.04 configure input/output devices

Tags: ubuntu, audio, microphone

Well, i have changed some alsa configuration.

Now the /etc/asound.conf file is:

```
#pcm.!default
#{
#   playback.pcm{
#       type hw
#       card 1
#       #device 1
#       rate 44100
#   }

#   playback.capture{
#       type hw
#       card 1
#       #device 0
#       rate 44100
#   }
#}

pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
    rate 44100
}

#   ctl.!default {
#   type hw           
#   card 1
#}
```

[image]

From front Left sound from sound device.
From front center sound from microphone.
From other options no sound.

[image]

I cannot record sound from microphone (no red bars under input device)

Any help would be usefull.

Comment: Re post from stackoverflow (original post has been deleted).